# MVC - check if password was entered correctly

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and I'm currently creating the backend for a Web application using servlets. I've heard that all the processing has to go into the model.

So in my model I get the data from the database and compare it to the value that I got from the request object.

Now one of my mates said, that this logic belongs to the authentification and has thus to go into the controller.

I'm pretty confused now and hope someone can help me out where to actually put that functionality. The model or the controller.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking Password onsubmit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218325/checking-password-onsubmit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is only a class that describes your DB related entity. You should not use this class to implement a CRUD operation. You need to use a DAO (a class that performs only crud operations on specific classes) and a Controller (your servlet) that uses this DAO to query db.

The DAO has methods like

```
public void save(entity entity);
public Entity loadById(Long id);
etc etc...
```

You have to think in this way : 
When you have to perform an action closely related to a Bean behaviour (for example calculate the total price for a Bean rappresenting Shopping Cart) you can implement this function (method) in model class (always called by a controller). 
All the other functions should be implemented in controller that manages 
functional logic.

You must distinguish between Model Classes, Controller Classes, View Classes, and Persistence Classes(DAO for CRUDS)

Comment: Take a look at this article :http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074052/design-patterns/write-once--persist-anywhere.html?page=2

Answer (score 0):

The *model* is the data itself, in this case the "user" or the "password" class.

In my opinion the correct place is the *controller*: it checks if data are correct (password, birth date and so on).

In this way you can reuse your model with a different logic without changing the "User" class. For example you can add a simple max-retry-attempts system and leave the User class original

But if you want to prevent an ajax call,